# estimate for $\int |f|d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure-space with $\mu$ a finite measure (i.e. $\mu(A)<\infty$ for all $A\in\mathcal A$) and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ a measurable function. Prove that:

1) $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(\{|f|\geq n\})\leq\int |f|d\mu\leq\mu(\Omega)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(\{|f|\geq n\})$$

2) $f$ is $\mu$-integrable if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(\{|f|\geq n\})$ converges.

I don't really know how to start this. I think the $\Leftarrow$-part of 2) follows from 1) because if the sum converges the integral $\int |f|d\mu$ is finite, too.

But how can I estimate the sums by the integral?

Comment: In fact $2) \Rightarrow 1)$ in all directions. For proving $1)$, first consider step functions
$$f_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}$$
With $A_i$ disjoint and $\alpha_i > \alpha_{i+1} \quad \forall i$.
You might want to take a look at the decreasing rearrangement ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n = |f|^{-1} ([n,n+1))$. We have $n \le |f(x)| < n+1$ for all $x \in S_n$.
Hence $\sum_n n 1_{S_n} \le |f| < \sum_n (n+1) 1_{S_n} $.

Now find a relationship between the $S_n$ and $\mu \{ x | |f(x)| \ge n \}$.

**Addendum**:

Note that $\Omega = \cup_{n=0}^\infty S_n$.

Note that $U_n = \{ x | |f(x)| \ge n \} = \cup_{k=n}^\infty\{ x | |f(x)| \in [k,k+1) \}   = \cup_{k=n}^\infty S_k$. Since the $S_k$ are disjoint, we can write 
$1_{U_n} = \sum_{k=n}^\infty 1_{S_k}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{U_n} &=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty 1_{S_k} \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^k 1_{S_k} \\
&=&  \sum_{k=1}^\infty k 1_{S_k} \\ 
&=&  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n 1_{S_n}
\end{eqnarray}

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu \{ x | |f(x)| \ge n \} &=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int 1_{U_n} \\
&=& \int \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{U_n}  \\
&=& \int \sum_{n=1}^\infty n 1_{S_n} \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int n 1_{S_n} 
\end{eqnarray}

Finally,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n 1_{S_n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n 1_{S_n} \le |f| < \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) 1_{S_n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n 1_{S_n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty  1_{S_n}  = 1+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty n 1_{S_n} = 1+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n 1_{S_n}
$$
and integrating gives
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu \{ x | |f(x)| \ge n \}  \le \int |f| \le \mu \Omega + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu \{ x | |f(x)| \ge n \} $.

Comment: I did some thinking on this, but I don't quite get this. $\sum_n n1_{S_n}$ reminds me of the definition of the integral for simple functions, but I don't quite get to $\{x|\, |f(x)|\geq n\}$ with this.

Comment: @dinosaur: I added some detail.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help! Thank you very very much!